# newValue is not empty when appending empty array

Tags: swift

I am trying to append newValue to local database, but I encountered weird issue when I found adding empty array duplicates current data in the array. so how to work around this issue?

```
var _strings  = ["0"]
var strings: [String]{
    set {
        // ... append newValue to local database
        _strings.append(contentsOf: newValue) // newValue = ["0"] not empty
    }
    get {
        return _strings
    }
}

strings.append(contentsOf: [])
print(strings) // prints ["0","0"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't append an empty array. Let's have a closer look what the line

```
strings.append(contentsOf: [])
```

does.

- `strings` calls it's getter which returns `["0"]` from `_strings`.
- `append` appends the empty array to `["0"]` which doesn't change anything in practice.
- Then the setter of `strings` is called and appends `newValue` (`["0"]`)

The backing underscore variable makes no sense in this case. Just declare

```
var strings = ["0"]
```

and delete everything else

Comment: thanks for your answer. So what's the proper way to handle added new content to array??

Comment: Delete `_strings` and the computed getter and setter in `strings`. Backing *instance* variables are *objective-c-ish*

Comment: but by deleting the setter, I will not be able to handle new added content, so what's your advice?

Comment: I mean use only `strings` as stored property. Declare `var strings = ["0"]` and forget the rest. Then `strings.append(contentsOf: [])` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear, but as I can understand you want to append the data of an array to another array, plz check below code.

```
import UIKit

var strings: [String]  = ["0"]

var strings2: [String]  = ["1", "2"]

strings.append(contentsOf: [])
print(strings) // prints ["0"] (here since the added array is empty nothing will be added.)

strings.append(contentsOf: strings2)
print(strings) // prints ["0", "1", "2"]
```